# How to prompt with the current Windows user's identity hint in ADAL AcquireToken

Tags: adal

When using the ADAL client to perform federated login, the `authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri, userId)` overload of `AcquireToken` will not show the `WindowsIdentity.Name` (i.e. `Domain\User` as the login name, despite being able to authenticate with that style of user name. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretoken.aspx) of [AcquireToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn528706.aspx) does not mention any requirements related to the userId parameter.

What are the requirements to send a user Id prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `AcquireToken` overload requires the user ID (login hint, once it's converted into an OAuth2 message under the abstraction) to be an email-formatted UPN.

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName` is the most convenient route to the interactive ActiveDirectory user's UPN I've found so far. Notably, this isn't a claim on the default `WindowsIdentity` `ClaimsIdentity`.